# Texture showing as black on one website but not another?

Tags: logo, texture

I made a logo for my student radio show on Illustrator and added a texture to the artwork. White texture showing through. Saved as PNG and it looked great. Uploaded to twitter and it looked great. Uploaded to the station website and the texture suddenly shows through as black!

Here it is on the site: https://www.camfm.co.uk/shows/world-town/

I am very new to all of this. Followed a tutorial on youtube.

Here is the original image:

[image: original image]

Comment: The image you link to is a JPEG so it has been converted somewhere. Would that make the difference? JPEG does not support transparency; maybe your 'white' PNG was actually transparent in those places. You can add your original to this post, by the way, so we have something to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I've added the original image

Comment: @Megan, the root of the issue is that the texture is not white, [it's transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhHWV.gif). And for some reason the site you uploaded it to converted it to a jpeg with matte color black. They didn't have to, but they did and you can do nothing about that. You can make sure the png has a white background, which would prevent the site from adding it in the conversion. Alternatively, you could make sure the texture is not a cutout but a white color fill instead.

Comment: File format technically doesn't seem to matter as they clearly can take in png files, but you would've avoided this issue by saving a jpeg as jpeg doesn't support transparency... or like I said, making sure it has no transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add another white(not transparent ) layer in photoshop with the png on top. and save it as jpg and it should look good.

if that's not possible, send me the high quality photo using some cloud link, I'll do it. just like I did for this :

[image: image.jpg]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. I will give it a go tomorrow. Although I will try saving as PNG again first as I always have trouble with JPEGs (pixelation around the lettering).